# every additional item on list is cascading with an additional indent

Tags: html

I am trying to repeat a div .box (5) times (using the same exact material in each box for now, will change content after) and every line is more indented than the next.

Here is a link to my code: http://jsfiddle.net/infoed/DN8x4/1/:

```
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>

<head>
    <title> Breaditt </title>
    <style>

html, body {
font-family: sans-serif;
margin: 0;
padding: 0; }


#logobar {
background: rgb(206, 211, 255); }


#logobar ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 40;
padding: 40; }

#logobar li {
display: inline;
padding: 20;
font-size: 52;
font-family: Comic sans MS;}

.box {
margin-left: 50px;
width: 650px;
height: 80px;
display: inline-block; }

.box .headline  {
font-size: 18px;
color: black;
list-style-type: none; 
display: inline-block; }

.box .submitted {
display: inline-block; }

.box h {
display: inline-block; }

.box img {
float: left;
margin-right: 10px;
}

.box {
clear:both;
}




    </style>
</head>


<body>

    <div id="logobar">
        <ul>
        <li>Breaditt: Bread News Aggregator</li>

        <li><img src="img/logo.jpg" alt="breaditt cat" width="250" height="200"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>


    <div id="breadnews">
        <div class="box">
        <img src="img/counter.jpg" alt=counter width="75" height="75" />
        <img src="img/bread.jpg" alt=article-logo width="75" height="75" />
        <div class="headline"><a href="http://breadcats.tumblr.com">Website dedicated to cats with bread</a> </div>
        <div class="submitted"><h>submitted 2 days ago by Alex Doggrowski</h> </div>
        <div class="share"><h>14,400 Comments. Share    Save    hide    report</h> </div>

        <div id="breadnews">
        <div class="box">
        <img src="img/counter.jpg" alt=counter width="75" height="75" />
        <img src="img/bread.jpg" alt=article-logo width="75" height="75" />
        <div class="headline"><a href="http://breadcats.tumblr.com">Website dedicated to cats with bread</a> </div>
        <div class="submitted"><h>submitted 2 days ago by Alex Doggrowski</h> </div>
        <div class="share"><h>14,400 Comments. Share    Save    hide    report</h> </div>

        <div id="breadnews">
        <div class="box">
        <img src="img/counter.jpg" alt=counter width="75" height="75" />
        <img src="img/bread.jpg" alt=article-logo width="75" height="75" />
        <div class="headline"><a href="http://breadcats.tumblr.com">Website dedicated to cats with bread</a> </div>
        <div class="submitted"><h>submitted 2 days ago by Alex Doggrowski</h> </div>
        <div class="share"><h>14,400 Comments. Share    Save    hide    report</h> </div>

        <div id="breadnews">
        <div class="box">
        <img src="img/counter.jpg" alt=counter width="75" height="75" />
        <img src="img/bread.jpg" alt=article-logo width="75" height="75" />
        <div class="headline"><a href="http://breadcats.tumblr.com">Website dedicated to cats with bread</a> </div>
        <div class="submitted"><h>submitted 2 days ago by Alex Doggrowski</h> </div>
        <div class="share"><h>14,400 Comments. Share    Save    hide    report</h> </div>

        <div id="breadnews">
        <div class="box">
        <img src="img/counter.jpg" alt=counter width="75" height="75" />
        <img src="img/bread.jpg" alt=article-logo width="75" height="75" />
        <div class="headline"><a href="http://breadcats.tumblr.com">Website dedicated to cats with bread</a> </div>
        <div class="submitted"><h>submitted 2 days ago by Alex Doggrowski</h> </div>
        <div class="share"><h>14,400 Comments. Share    Save    hide    report</h> </div>



        </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You repeatedly open `<div id="breadnews">` and `<div class="box">`, but you never close either.

For starters, IDs MUST be unique, so you probably meant to not copy-paste the `<div id="breadnews">` line. After that, just add `</div>` after each block and you should be good.

Also, please use JSFiddle *correctly*. Don't shove everything in the HTML box when there's perfectly usable CSS and JS boxes. Finally, it's `<!DOCTYPE html>`, not `<doctype! html>`.

Comment: Ok, I fixed the DOCTYPE! and will put css styles in the css box next time. It is my first time using that service. Thanks for the help. I closed each div and it lists correctly.

Comment: I was not award a ID must be unique. I thought the id="breadnews" refers to the fact that each item is a "news box" no?

Comment: "ID" stands for "identification" which stems from "identity", which means ONE. Perhaps you intended to use `class="breadnews"` (and `.breadnews` in the CSS) instead, to define a type of element there may be more than one of.

Answer (score 0):

All of Kolink's points are correct.  Here is an updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/DN8x4/4/

```
    <div id="logobar">
        <ul>
        <li>Breaditt: Bread News Aggregator</li>

            <li><img src="img/logo.jpg" alt="breaditt cat" width="250" height="200" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>


    <div id="breadnews">
        <div class="box">
        <img src="img/counter.jpg" alt=counter width="75" height="75" />
        <img src="img/bread.jpg" alt=article-logo width="75" height="75" />
        <div class="headline"><a href="http://breadcats.tumblr.com">Website dedicated to cats with bread</a> </div>
        <div class="submitted"><h>submitted 2 days ago by Alex Doggrowski</h> </div>
            <div class="share"><h>14,400 Comments. Share    Save    hide    report</h> </div></div>

        <div id="breadnews">
        <div class="box">
        <img src="img/counter.jpg" alt=counter width="75" height="75" />
        <img src="img/bread.jpg" alt=article-logo width="75" height="75" />
        <div class="headline"><a href="http://breadcats.tumblr.com">Website dedicated to cats with bread</a> </div>
        <div class="submitted"><h>submitted 2 days ago by Alex Doggrowski</h> </div>
            <div class="share"><h>14,400 Comments. Share    Save    hide    report</h> </div></div>

        <div id="breadnews">
        <div class="box">
        <img src="img/counter.jpg" alt=counter width="75" height="75" />
        <img src="img/bread.jpg" alt=article-logo width="75" height="75" />
        <div class="headline"><a href="http://breadcats.tumblr.com">Website dedicated to cats with bread</a> </div>
        <div class="submitted"><h>submitted 2 days ago by Alex Doggrowski</h> </div>
            <div class="share"><h>14,400 Comments. Share    Save    hide    report</h> </div></div>

        <div id="breadnews">
        <div class="box">
        <img src="img/counter.jpg" alt=counter width="75" height="75" />
        <img src="img/bread.jpg" alt=article-logo width="75" height="75" />
        <div class="headline"><a href="http://breadcats.tumblr.com">Website dedicated to cats with bread</a> </div>
        <div class="submitted"><h>submitted 2 days ago by Alex Doggrowski</h> </div>
            <div class="share"><h>14,400 Comments. Share    Save    hide    report</h> </div></div>

        <div id="breadnews">
        <div class="box">
        <img src="img/counter.jpg" alt=counter width="75" height="75" />
        <img src="img/bread.jpg" alt=article-logo width="75" height="75" />
        <div class="headline"><a href="http://breadcats.tumblr.com">Website dedicated to cats with bread</a> </div>
        <div class="submitted"><h>submitted 2 days ago by Alex Doggrowski</h> </div>
            <div class="share"><h>14,400 Comments. Share    Save    hide    report</h> </div>



        </div>
```

The markup still needs some work (e.g. fixing duplicate ids).

Answer (score 0):

Your `<div class="box">`'s are not closed.,  See:

http://jsfiddle.net/DN8x4/5/